# How to slide a two images at same time on button click in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to slide only just two images on button click like when button is clicked then assume

two images should slide at a same time

Like i have two div of images

```
  <div class="imageone"><img src="one.png"/></div>
  <div class="imagetwo"><img src="two.png"/></div>
```

they should scroll at a same time

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function(){
 $(".imageone, .imagetwo").slideUp();
});
```

or you can use animate() to move the images

Comment: it looks good but i want that on not click function but when div is loaded frist image should slide come first and then second

Comment: i want that on button click it should slide and by default there should be no any image shown

Comment: yes i want like this but slide can be from right to left or not

Comment: you can slide them from right to left using jquery animate() http://api.jquery.com/animate.

Comment: i don't want click on any div i want just above as we done like that but sliding should be from right to left